# Closure of $f\mapsto{\rm i}f'$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces, adjoint-operators

Let $$\begin{split}\mathcal D(T_3)&:=\left\{f\in L^2([0,1];\mathbb C):f\text{ is absolutely continuous with }f'\in L^2([0,1];\mathbb C)\right\},\\\mathcal D(T_2)&:=\left\{f\in\mathcal D(T_3):f(0)=f(1)\right\},\\\mathcal D(T_1)&:=\left\{f\in\mathcal D(T_2):f(0)=0\right\},\\\mathcal D(T_0)&:=\mathcal D(T_1)\cap C^\infty([0,1];\mathbb C)\end{split}$$ and $$T_k:={\rm i}f'\;\;\;\text{for }\mathcal D(T_k)\text{ and }k\in\{0,\ldots,3\}.$$

> What's the easiest way to observe that $T_0$ is closable and $\overline{T_0}=T_1$?

First of all, $T_0$ should be densely-defined, since $C([0,1];\mathbb C)$ is dense in $L^2([0,1];\mathbb C)$, right? Now, how do we observe that $T_1$ is closed? I was able to show that $T_1^\ast=T_3$ which yields that $T_3$ is closed (since the adjoint is always closed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity, forget about the imaginary unit $i$, we are to show that, for $f_{n}\rightarrow f$ in $L^{2}$, and $f_{n}'\rightarrow g$ in $L^{2}$, it will follow that $g=f'$ a.e.

Since $\|\cdot\|_{L^{1}[0,1]}\leq\|\cdot\|_{L^{2}[0,1]}$, it is easy to see that
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{x}g(t)dt=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{0}^{x}f_{n}'(t)dt=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_{n}(x)
\end{align*}
But $f_{n}\rightarrow f$ in $L^{2}$ entails an almost everywhere pointwise convergent subsequence $f_{n_{k}}(x)\rightarrow f(x)$, this leads to
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{x}g(t)dt=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}f_{n_{k}}(x)=f(x)~~~~\text{a.e.}
\end{align*}
We are done.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There's one thing I'm curious about: I know that an absolutely continuous function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb C$ is differentiable almost everywhere in the open interval $(a,b)$ and $f'\in L^1((a,b))$. However, in order for $T_k$ to be an operator on $L^2([a,b])$ (with the closed interval $[a,b]$), we need to identify treat $f'\in L^1([a,b])$ ... I mean, that shouldn't be a problem, since $\{a,b\}$ is just another null set and hence we should still be able to say that $f'$ exists almost everywhere in $[a,b]$ ... Or is there anything we need to worry about?

Comment: I think a.e. is sufficient for this matter.

Comment: So, you agree that we can treat $f'$ as an element (a representative of a equivalence class of) $L^2([a,b])$?

Comment: You must do it in this way, or else how do we talk about $L^{2}$?

Comment: Well, $T_k$ could be an operator from $L^2([a,b])$ to $L^2((a,b))$, couldn't it?

Comment: No matter which one you choose, I don't think that will cause any problem, thanks to the a.e. thing.

Comment: Yes, I guess so. Thanks.

Comment: Another subtlety: You claim that $\int_{0}^{x}g(t)dt=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_{n}(x)$ for a.e. $x$, but shouldn't this hold for *every* $x$? Where does the exclusion of a null set came from?

Comment: Okay, I just realized that it should be everywhere.

Comment: Ah, I was just curious whether I'm missing something.

Comment: Would we loose the closedness for $T_2$ and $T_3$? It seems to be crucial that $f_n(0)=0$, since we otherwise wouldn't know whether $(f_n(0))_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges or not.

Comment: When we prove the closedness, those $f_{n}$ and $f$ that we pick from the domain, they already satisfy the condition that $f_{n}(0)=f(0)=0$, because we really pick from the domain.

Comment: Yes, I know. That's the question. What if we pick $f_n$ from $\mathcal D(T_2)$ or $\mathcal D(T_3)$ or, phrased differently, are $T_2$ and $T_3$ closed as well?

Comment: I have thought seriously this issue just now. I need to make a correction. For we take $f_{n}$ from the domain, not the $f$, so $f(0)=0$ is not guaranteed. The annoying issue is that, if we assume that $f_{n}\rightarrow f$ in $L^{2}$ and $Tf_{n}\rightarrow g$, we can only show that $g=if'$. It is really that $f$ need no to be $f(0)=0$.

Comment: I think that the same thoughts yield another problem even for the closedness of $T_1$: In your answer, you've shown that $f'$ is differentiable almost everywhere in $[0,1]$ and $f'=-{\rm i}g\in L^2([a,b])$, but in order to conclude that $f\in\mathcal D(T_1)$ (which  we need for the closedness) we need $f(0)=f(1)=0$ as well. I don't see how we obtain that, since $f(x)=-{\rm i}\int_0^xg(t)\:{\rm d}t$ holds only for *almost* all $x\in[0,1]$ (not necessarily for $x=0$ and $x=1$). Am I missing something?

Comment: Give me one hour, I am fixing it.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for your effort.

Comment: I checked out some Hilbert space book. There is some similar discussion about this, but the domain is somewhat different than yours. They start with $C_{0}^{\infty}(a,b)$, this means that around $a$ those functions are having identically zero values. Anyway, see page 162, *Linear Operators in Hilbert Spaces*, Joachim Weidmann.

Comment: In my proof, the best you can say is that, $f$ admits an absolute continuous representative, in this case, which is simply $\varphi(x)=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{x}g(t)dt$, $\varphi(0)=0$. For convergence only in $L^{2}$, $f$ could be very bad, why is it necessarily to be absolutely continuous? So I think some additional information must be included in your question. But if everything is taken in the sense of equivalent class, it may go through anyway.

Comment: Well, okay, first of all: (a) $\tilde f(x):=-{\rm i}\int_0^xg(t)\:{\rm d}t$, for $x\in [0,1]$, is clearly absolutely continous, differentiable in $[0,1]$ with $\tilde f'=-{\rm i}g\in L^2([0,1])$ and hence $\tilde f\in\mathcal D(T_1)$. Moreover, $T_1\tilde f=g$ and $f=\tilde f$ a.e. (b) Now, isn't the definition of $\mathcal D(T_2)$ and $\mathcal D(T_1$ broken anyway? Enforcing $f(0)=f(1)$ or $f(0)=f(1)=0$ doesn't make sense for $f\in L^2([0,1])$,

Comment: since $f$ is actually an equivalence class and we may clearly modify any representative of this equivalence class on the null set $\{0,1\}$ without leaving this equivalence class. So, the conditions in the definition of $\mathcal D(T_2)$ and $\mathcal D(T_1)$ would need to be understood in the sense that they consist of equivalence classes $f$ which admit representatives $\tilde f$ satisfying $\tilde f(0)=\tilde f(1)$ and $\tilde f(0)=\tilde f(1)=0$, respectively. But again, this is achievable for any $f\in L^2([a,b])$ and hence doesn't make sense at all ...

Comment: But the same domains are considered in example 13.4 of Rudin's *Functional Analysis* (2nd edition) ... What am I missing?

Comment: That is not achievable for very $f\in L^{2}$ because there is an extra condition that being absolutely continuous (a representative).

Comment: Oops, I was missing that for a moment. Well, then this must be the way we need to understand this: There is an absolutely continuous representative satisfying these conditions.

Comment: The only thing left is why is $T_0$ closable?

Comment: As long as you are able to prove that $\overline{T_{0}}=T_{1}$, then it is.

Comment: I'm not sure if I able to prove that. Actually, $\overline{T_0}$ is always well-defined if we consider it as a multi-valued operator (i.e. identify $T_0$ with its graph for which the closure is clearly well-defined). With this I'm able to prove that $T_1\subseteq\overline{T_0}$. What's left is then that $\overline{T_0}$ is single-valued.