# Is the $L^2$-limit of absolutely continuous functions absolutely continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Let $a<b$ and call $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb C$ *absolutely continuous* if there is a $h\in L^2((a,b))$ with $$f(x)-f(a)=\int_a^xh(y)\:{\rm d}y\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in[a,b]\tag1.$$  Assume $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq L^2([a,b])$ is a sequence of absolutely continuous functions with $f_n(a)=f_n(b)=0$ and $f\in L^2([a,b])$ with $f_n\to f$ in $L^2([a,b])$. Does it follow that $f$ is absolutely continuous?

By assumption, there are $h_n\in L^2((a,b))$ with $f_n(x)=\int_a^xh_n(y)\:{\rm d}y$. Now, my guess is that we need to show that $(h_n)$ is Cauchy in $L^2((a,b))$ and then conclude by completeness. Are we able to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to show that $(h_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $L^2$, and no, it's not possible to show that. For example say $(a,b)=(-1,1)$ and $h_n=n\chi_{(0,1/n)}$.

**Or**, to make it seem more face-palm obvious, note that the trigonometric polynomials are dense in $L^2((0,2\pi))$. (I said "seem": I don't think thiis really gives a simpler counterexampple, because we need to verify that the tps with $p(0)=0$ are dense, which is no easier than the triviality above. But I do think it makes it "clear" that the answer "must be" no...)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Well, I've tried to show this since I actually think we need this to conclude that the operator $T_3$ in [my other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3485491/47771) is closed. What am I missing?

Comment: @0xbadf00d To show $T$ is closed you assume $f_n\to f$ and $Tf_n\to g$ and you have to show $Tf=g$.  My best guess is what you're missing is the extra information we get from $T_3f_n\to g$.

Comment: Oh, lord. I guess it' simply $$\int|h_m-h_n|^2=\int|(f_m-f_n)'|^2\to0,$$ where $h_n\in L^2$ with $f_n=\int_0^{\;\cdot}h_n$.